# Convert JavaFX to JApplet with NetBeans 8

Tags: java, maven, javafx, japplet, netbeans-8

May be this is already answered before, but I have not found it.

I have a JavaFX project using Maven made with NetBeans 8.0.2 and I need to convert it to JApplet to be able to run it on a web browser.

I try to find something about how to do that without any luck on how to do it exactly.

Comment: Don't use applets in 2015. Use JNLP. Which means there is no need to modify your application: just create a JNLP descriptor.

Comment: You can use the [JavaFX packaging tools](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) to create both an applet (highly not recommended) and a Java Web Start (i.e. JNLP file) application directly: there is no need to wrap it in a Swing `JApplet`. The packaging tools come as a command-line tool and an Ant task. I don't use NetBeans, but I'm pretty sure that if you create a JavaFX project there are wizards for running the packaging. (E(fx)clipse certainly has these.)

Comment: I agree with @fge and the other comment.  The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It can work (the app. is launched from a link on a web page) and will be both more reliable and less hassle than an applet.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it's been a really long time since I did something in java, I didn't knew about JNLP. Thanks a lot.